# Java: Method is Not Applicable for Arguments

Tags: java

Okay.  So, I'm a kid, trying to program a cool little 3d game, and then this... *issue* decides to take a crap on my next few days.

I'm using Eclipse for my IDE.  When I insert `controls.tick(forward, back, left, right, turnLeft, turnRight);` ("controls" is, well, the controls for my game, and "tick" is the time which ties into steps, turning, time itself, etc.) Eclipse says `"The method 'tick'(boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean) in the type 'Controller' is not applicable for the arguments (boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean)"` and I'm beginning to get incredibly frustrated.  "forward, back, left, right, turnLeft, turnRight" are booleans designed to, well, be booleans, and prevent the camera from moving.  They are "linked" to keys that set it to true, to keep this short.  "Controller" is a .class file to "house" the controls, rotations, etc.

So, what's an in-depth response of what I'm doing wrong?  It's important I don't add or take away any booleans from what I have.  Is there any way around this, and may I have a walkthrough?

Here is my .class file that does the work:

```
package com.mime.ocelot;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import com.mime.ocelot.input.Controller;

public class Game {

public int time;
public Controller controls;

public Game() {

}

public void tick(boolean[] key) {
    time++;
    boolean forward = key[KeyEvent.VK_W];
    boolean back = key[KeyEvent.VK_S];
    boolean left = key[KeyEvent.VK_A];
    boolean right = key[KeyEvent.VK_D];
    boolean turnLeft = key[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT];
    boolean turnRight = key[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT];

    controls.tick(forward, back, left, right, turnLeft, turnRight);

}

}
```

And here's the .class that is the actual controller:

```
package com.mime.ocelot.input;

public class Controller {

public double x, z, rotation, xa, za, rotationa;

public void tick(boolean forward, boolean back, boolean right, boolean turnLeft, boolean turnRight) {

}

}
```

Comment: Any comments are appreciated.  I'm beginning to get sick of this crap.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just wanted to say that your writing style annoyed me.

Answer (score 7):

`tick()` is defined like this:

```
tick(boolean forward, boolean back, boolean right, boolean turnLeft, boolean turnRight)
```

It takes five boolean arguments. You call it like this:

```
tick(forward, back, left, right, turnLeft, turnRight);
```

You're trying to pass it six `boolean` arguments. It looks like you meant to define it like this:

```
tick(boolean forward, boolean back, boolean left, boolean right, boolean turnLeft, boolean turnRight)
```

---

Wow, I got six upvotes for pointing out that a parameter was missing in a function definition.

Comment: @citrus9wyo If I helped you (somehow, I'm guessing I might have), just upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Yeah, that's how I meant to format it.

Comment: and there you go, another upvote for honestly being surprised that what you pointed out should be so obvious as to not need any upvotes :) But then, you've found the problem, and that's what StackOverflow is partly about

Answer (score 1):

The tick method signature expects 5 booleans, though you are passing 6.  Change the tick method to:

```
public void tick(boolean forward, boolean back, boolean left, boolean right, boolean turnLeft, boolean turnRight)
```

Comment: This is almost identical to my answer, but with less explanation.